# why did this mysql table copy generate duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I did

```
insert  t1  select *  from  t2;
```

to copy a table, after creating t1 by

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  `c` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `d` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `d2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

A count of original and duplicate tables shows 69M vs. 80M rows , and indeed I see duplicate rows in the copied table - does someone know why this can happen?  The original table was innodb and copy is myisam, perhaps this is the source of the dupication?

Comment: It can't. Something else is happening.btw I would select named fields.

Comment: Most likely the t1table already contained records before the insert?

Comment: Are you sure t2 is without duplicates? Sure t1 was emtpy before?

Comment: Ups, same idea like Raymond ... :D

Comment: I guess raymond/christophs must be right, I tried again with a new t1 and get identical table sizes this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize:

Ensure table t1 is empty before copy

```
truncate t1;
```

then copy the way you have done before and count again.